# How to see all output when executing `docker build`

Tags: bash, docker

The `docker build` is scrolling the output.

```
docker build -t "setuppython"  .
```

In the screenshot the area enclosed in the red rectangle is being scrolled - and the prior output is lost.  I would like to be able to see all output without it being hidden:

[image]

Here is the `Dockerfile`

```
from ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR .
RUN echo "HOME is $HOME"
COPY  ./setup-python.sh .

RUN ./setup-python.sh
```

How can that be done?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set the `--progress=plain` option, so modify the build command as follows:

```
docker build -t "setuppython" --progress=plain .
```

Alternatively, you can set the `BUILDKIT_PROGRESS` environment variable ([documented here](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/env-vars/#buildkit_progress)) instead of explicitly setting this option for each individual build command, like so:

```
export BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain
```

The `--progress` argument and/or the `BUILDKIT_PROGRESS` environment variable accept the values `auto`, `plain`, and `tty`. Using `tty`, the output will try to be "nicer" for interactive terminals (so it overwrites itself), and `plain` will simply output everything. The `auto` setting (default) will try to determine which of the two is more appropriate for the current environment.

Comment: Anyone know if there is an environment variable or setting to make "plain" the default? Of course I can make an alias for "docker --progress=plain", but I think it would be better if it was configurable.

Comment: @Bjorn I updated the answer to include the environment variable setting. So to answer your question; yes there is - and it is `BUILDKIT_PROGRESS` :)